# SpringBoot works on the web but doesn't work in the postman?

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I'm trying to build to build a really basic user/role CRUD with spring security.

I created 2 types of accounts: admin and user.

After I go to this URL: http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees first I get login and after that I get the result
[image: Sign in]

[image: Result of URL]

The problem start when I try to connect via postman. I can't get past the login.
[image: Login fail]

I can't get past the login no matter what. I tried other controller but the same thing happens.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem yesterday, it's most likely the same thing.

I disabled csrf in the class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to get it to work. If you're moving into production, you should probably leave it enabled.

My `WebSecurityConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }
}
```

I don't fully understand how the csrf protection so there might be issues if you try to log in from a browser. Uncomment out the `.csrf().disable()` when you want to run in from a browser

Comment: That wasn't it. Still can't login.

Comment: Update your post with the controller method that maps to api/v1/employees. And the equivalent of WebSecurityConfig class

Answer (score 0):

To make a call in Postman, you need to pass a proper authorization (token header/cookie) when calling an endpoint. In your current case, Postman either shows you a login page which is that HTML you see, or an error page because unauthorized